# Does the Laravel Mix Polyfill extension not include the String.includes method?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, polyfills

I'm using the Laravel Mix Polyfill extension (https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill) with a Laravel and Vue.js project.

When I import `vue-select` into a Vue file, I get the following error in IE11:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

This seems weird to me, as I assumed that the Polyfill extension was explicitly designed to polyfill these types of things in IE11, etc.

If I add the following block above my import statement for `vue-select` (credit to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill), then everything works fine, but I would ideally not like to do this and just rely on the Polyfill extension to manage all of this for me:

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
    String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
        'use strict';

        if (search instanceof RegExp) {
            throw TypeError('first argument must not be a RegExp');
        }

        if (start === undefined) {
            start = 0; 
        }

        return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    };
}
```

The Polyfill extension is working properly for promises in IE11, so I'm assuming that it is installed and set up correctly in my project, but I'm wondering what's up with the `String.includes` method specifically.

Does anyone know? Thanks.

**Edit #1**: Here's what I have set for the `polyfill` method in the `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
.polyfill({
    enabled: true,
    useBuiltIns: 'usage'
});
```

Comment: You don't have `useBuiltIns` set to false, so you?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that. Thank you.